# How to update product price with graphql on shopify if there is no product variant

Tags: graphql, shopify

I am using a python script with requests to update various properties of a shopify shop using graphql and it works fine.

The problem is I can't figure out how to update a product price when there is no product variant using **Graphql**

All the documentation refers to mutations on product variants, but most of the products on this shop don't have any variants.

However I read somewhere that products without variants are "default variants" themselves, but i can't find the id for this.

If I pass the product id, or global id, the response is just no id found.
I have spent hours on the documentation and I can't find the correct reference.
I even asked our banned friend, but wasn't really helpful:)

Here is the working graphql query for updating variants for reference.

```
query = '''
    mutation productVariantUpdate($input1: ProductVariantInput!) {
              item1: productVariantUpdate(input: $input1) {
                productVariant {
                  id,
                  price
                }
                userErrors {
                  field
                  message
                }
            }
    '''

variables = {
                "input2":{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/42177699971252","price":15.20}
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A product has many variants. Between one, and one hundred. End of story. If you have a product ID, you can get the variant IDs. End of story. If you have a variant ID, you can get the variant details. With those, you will find that a variant has an inventory_item_id. Or inventoryItemId. You get the picture? With that, you can get the item! The item has a price. You can use a mutation to set the price. That is how it is done.

If you say you have a product without a variant, that is false. Impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're confusing the number of *options* with variants.

The [Product object](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/objects/Product#field-product-hasonlydefaultvariant) also has a `totalVariants` count and `hasOnlyDefaultVariant` fields

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
The confusing part was, when you have a product the uri has a product id, if you create a variant, there is a variant id in the uri as well.
But i didn't realize that the existance of a default variant id as i never came across of this in the gui, so i never tried to run a variant query on a product without multiple variants.

So running:

```
 {
  product(id: "gid://shopify/Product/123456798"){    
    variants(first:5 ){ 
      nodes {
        id
        price
      }
    }    
  }      
}
```

Does return the dafault variant id which i can then use for updating.

Comment: I'd be careful there. You have no clue about the exact variants returned other than, if there is one, you get one, and if there are five, you get five, but if there are 73, you only get five. So for accuracy sake, your script is sadly missing the logic to ensure that if you are pricing products, you're pricing all of them. Structure your code to deal with 1 to 100 variants, and you'll be safe as houses for all use cases!